# White space added before table coded with Magento WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html, magento, wysiwyg

This may be a simple issue, but I couldn't find where it come from.
I am using Magento WYSIWYG editor to enter product description with a table content. every thing look fine in Magento admin with WYSIWYG editor (no white space). But, the page output give a huge white space before the table appears. I recently upgraded to Magento CE 1.8.1, and I am not sure if this issue is related to the upgrade or not.

Here is the code in WYSIWYG editor.

```
<p><span style="font-size: medium;">T8 Tube</span></p>
<table style="width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<colgroup><col width="128" /></colgroup>
<colgroup><col width="77" /></colgroup>
<colgroup><col width="80" /></colgroup>
<colgroup><col width="92" /></colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="128" height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size:medium;">Wattage</span></td>
<td width="77"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">9W</span></td>
<td width="80"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">13W</span></td>
<td width="92"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">18W</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">voltage(VAC)</span>    
</td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">Lumens (lm)</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">850</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">1250</span></td>
<td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">1750</span></td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

When I open browser with view code I got below output

```
 <p><span style="font-size: medium;">T8 Tube</span></p><br />
 <table style="width: 400px;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"><br />
 <colgroup><col width="128" /></colgroup><br />
 <colgroup><col width="77" /></colgroup><br />
 <colgroup><col width="80" /></colgroup><br />
 <colgroup><col width="92" /></colgroup><br />
 <tbody><br />
 <tr><br />
 <td width="128" height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">Wattage</span></td><br />
 <td width="77"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">9W</span></td><br />
 <td width="80"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">13W</span></td><br />
 <td width="92"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">18W</span></td><br />
 </tr><br />
 <tr><br />
 <td height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">voltage (VAC)</span> </td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">220-240</span></td><br />
 </tr><br />
 <tr><br />
 <td height="19"><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">Lumens (lm)</span></td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">850</span></td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">1250</span></td><br />
 <td><span style="color: #000000; font-size: medium;">1750</span></td><br />
 </tr><br />
 </tbody><br />
 </table><br />
```

So every table tag was added with break tag which create the big white space before table in page.
I have no idea how and who added these break tag behind each table tag. there is no white space when I check the content with WYSIWYG editor in Magento admin. Anybody help? thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post link to page?

Comment: Ok, I didn't know Magento add break tag to every single tag of description content by default...it may be acceptable with text content but not for table obviously. I mean if you forced adding break tag by using nr2br function, you need to make the function smart enough to recognize some tag as a whole content such as table tag. Very sad for Magento such big project!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you put your table through html compression, it will not put any white space.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not know this yet like me in two days ago.... Just remove nr2br function call and leave those content there in view.phtml file. The function actually add break tag to every single tag in your description content....